# How can I extend the reach of my antenna?

Tags: rfid

I have a PN532 Board working with my Raspberry Pi to read and write to MIFARE Tags.  I want to be able to do this with tags that are about a foot away, not just a couple centimetres.

What can I do to extend the reach of my antenna?  Code-wise and/or hardware-wise?  I would appreciate some very specific instructions as I am totally new to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'simple' fix to increase the range of your board.
You'd have to redesign the Tx/Rx pickup antenna to get greater distance. 
There are details of the antenna design [here](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PN532_AntennaDesign_v1.0.pdf), which I hope highlights the complexity of the task.
You need to understand the datasheet for the PN532 and may get more help from the NXP application note [AN1445](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN1445_An1444.zip) on NFC antennas.